# Using DayCounter ActualActual.ISMA in QuantLib

Tags: fixed-income, bond, python, quantlib, daycounting

Suppose we have a semiannual coupon bond. The calculation date is 5/8 2017. The ex-coupon date is 4/20 2017 and next coupon date is 10/20 2017.

```
    issue_date= Date(20,10,2001)
    maturity_date=Date(20, 10, 2021)
    tenor=Period(2)
    calendar=China()
    business_convention=Unadjusted
    date_generation=DateGeneration.Backward
    month_end=False
    schedule=Schedule(issue_date,maturity_date,tenor,calendar,business_convention,business_convention,date_generation,month_end)
    day_count= ActualActual(ActualActual.ISMA,schedule)
```

When I define the `day_count`, I specify the type and the coupon schedule. There are 165 days between 5/8 2017 and 10/20 2017, and 183 days in this period. This should be 0.4508(which is divided by frequency). Actually, I can get this by defining the coupon period:

```
    day_count.yearFraction(calc_date,Date(20,10,2017),Date(20,4,2017),Date(20,10,2017))
    Out[1]: 0.45081967213114754
```

However, when I directly enter the `calc_date`, it returns a strange result.

```
    day_count.yearFraction(calc_date,Date(20,10,2017))
    Out[2]: 0.4166666666666667
```

I think this will change the npv when I construct `FlatForward` yield curve and `FixedRateBond`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example (when no period is specified), the **ActualActual.ISMA** DayCounter basically returns

```
  RoundedNumberOfMonthsBetween(date1,date2) / 12 = 5 / 12 = 0.41666
```

whereas in the first one (when there is a specific period) some *fancy* adjustments are made based on the difference in days (20 - 8 + halfday = 12.5):

```
  RoundedNumberOfMonthsBetween(date1,date2) / 12 + 12.5/365 ≈ 0.4508
```

I am not entirely familiar with the exact adjustment. But for more details have a look at

- https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/time/daycounters/actualactual.cpp#L44
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#Actual/Actual_ICMA

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! But it seems that `schedule`doesn't work as I thought. It should use the schedule and fill out `refPeriodStart`. When I use this `day_count` in `FixedRateBond`, there is no place to enter `refPeriodStart`, right?

Comment: The fixed-rate bond knows the reference periods of its coupons and will pass them to the day counter.